# What's is the faster way to extract 1 terabyte of data from tables in SQL Server to Parquet files without hadoop

Tags: sql-server, performance, pandas, streaming, parquet

I need to extract 2 tables from a SQL Server Database to files in Apache Parquet (I don't use Hadoop, only parquet files). The options I know of are:

1. Load data to a dataframe in Pandas and save to parquet file. But, this method don't stream the data from SQL Server to Parquet, and i have 6 GB of RAM memory only.
2. Use [TurboODBC](https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc) to query SQL Server, convert the data to Apache Arrow on the fly and then convert to Parquet. Same problem that above, TurboODBC doesn't stream currently.

Does a tool or library exist that can easily and "quickly" extract the 1 TB of data from tables in SQL Server to parquet files?

Comment: probably better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing functionality you are looking for is the retrieval of the result in batches with Apache Arrow in Turbodbc instead of the whole Table at once: https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/133 You can either help with the implementation of this feature or use `fetchnumpybatches` to retrieve the result in a chunked fashion meanwhile.

In general, I would recommend you to not export the data as one big Parquet file but as many smaller ones, this will make working with them much easier. Mostly all engines/artifacts that can consume Parquet will be able to handle multiple files as one big dataset. You can then also split your query into multiple ones that write out the Parquet files in parallel. If you limit the export to chunks that are smaller than your total main memory, you should also be able to use `fetchallarrow` to write to Parquet at once.

Comment: `"not export the data as one big Parquet file but as many smaller ones"` - i think it's very valuable advice - this can make a lot of things easier in future +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, i don't know C++ and know Python in beginner level. I like the option to use  fetchallarrow and save to many files. I want Parket files to test it in Dremio and Azure Data Lake Analitycs, all with the same files. It's a researching i'm doing for work and to help to decide what's the best fit for a data lake in our enterprise.

Comment: Also, what's is the good practice relative to size of each parquet file, when the target is use that files for analitycs? 1GB?

Comment: Somewhere between 128MB and 1GB. Depending on your workload, you may need to check and tune. If your files are larger than 128MB, ensure that you set chunk_size in `pyarrow.parquet.write_table` to a value that you would get multiple chunks in a file (a chunk being roughly 128MB large).

Comment: Thanks you. Your answers are very valuable

Comment: Btw, the GitHub issue referenced was fixed in 2018. 
See documentation here: 
https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/advanced_usage.html#obtaining-apache-arrow-result-sets-in-batches

Answer (score 6):

I think the [odbc2parquet](https://github.com/pacman82/odbc2parquet) command line utility might be what you are looking for.

- Utilizes odbc bulk queries to retrieve data from SQL Server fast (like turbodbc).
- It only keeps one batch in memory at a time, so you can write parquet
  files which are larger than your system memory.
- Allows you to split the result into multiple files if desired.

Full disclosure, I am the author, so I might be biased towards the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking into the powershell scripts from Microsoft here.

Powershell script from that uses Parquet.NET or ParquetSharp underneath the hood. Very fast and can work with many tables. Not actively maintained but you can tweak the source code for your needs.

https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSynapseScriptsAndAccelerators/tree/main/Migration/SQLServer/2B_ExportSourceDataToParquet

```
.\Export-ToParquet.ps1 -ConfigFile .\ConfigFile.csv -ServerName "test_sql_server_instance" -UserName sqladminuser -MaxJobsCount 5
```